# Android - How to Send Image to other activity from load Image from SD Card

Tags: android-intent, android-imageview

i want to ask about send path image to other activity and show to imageview

BrowsePhoto.java

```
private static int PICK_FROM_FILE = 1;
private static int INTENT_IMAGE = 2;
private ImageButton buttonLoadImage;
private ImageButton reloadPhoto;
private ImageButton imagedone;
private ImageView mImageView;
private Uri mImageCaptureUri;
TextView textImagePath;

Uri imageUri = null;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.push_left_in, R.anim.hold);
    setContentView(R.layout.browse);

    buttonLoadImage = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnLoadImage);
    imagedone = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPhotoOk);
    reloadPhoto = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnReLoad);
    mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_pic);
    textImagePath = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.imagepath);

    buttonLoadImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

            startActivityForResult(
                    Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"),
                    PICK_FROM_FILE);

            buttonLoadImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            imagedone.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            reloadPhoto.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });

    findViewById(R.id.btnPhotoOk).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.btnReLoad).setOnClickListener(this);

}

public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btnPhotoOk:
        moveToEditPhotoDrawerActivity();

        break;
    case R.id.btnReLoad:
        backToBrowsePhotoDrawerActivity();
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}

private void moveToEditPhotoDrawerActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    startActivityForResult(intent, INTENT_IMAGE);
}

private void backToBrowsePhotoDrawerActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, BrowsePhoto.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK)
        return;

    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    String path = "";

    if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_FILE) {
        mImageCaptureUri = data.getData();

        path = getRealPathFromURI(mImageCaptureUri);

        if (path == null)
            path = mImageCaptureUri.getPath();

        if (path != null)
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
    } else {
        path = mImageCaptureUri.getPath();
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);


    }

    mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    textImagePath.setText(path.toString());

    if(requestCode == INTENT_IMAGE){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, EditImage.class);
        intent.putExtra("intent_image", path);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}

public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);

    if (cursor == null)
        return null;

    int column_index = cursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);

    cursor.moveToFirst();

    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

EditImage.java

```
    String picturePath = getIntent().getStringExtra("intent_image");
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_pic);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
```

Screenshoot after i load image from sd card

![Screenshoot after i load image from sd card][1]

and if i click button correct, then intent to editimage

what is wrong from the code?
if you help me, you saved my time :(

Comment: have you tried sending the file path in a bundle?

Comment: I've tried to use bundle ... but the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove these lines from your `onActivityResult`

```
if(requestCode == INTENT_IMAGE){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, EditImage.class);
    intent.putExtra("intent_image", path);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

and change `moveToEditPhotoDrawerActivity` with

```
    private void moveToEditPhotoDrawerActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, EditImage.class);
    intent.putExtra("intent_image", path);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: variable path from onActivityResult 
how to get path?

Comment: `String path=mImageCaptureUri.getPath();`

Comment: thanks :) .. and how to translate path to imagview in other activity? i use my code no picture / blank...

Comment: to display Image use same code `bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);` and then set `bitmap` to your `ImageView`

Comment: see my code EditImage.java ... is true? i try and not set picture and I try to get the path to the text view that can ...

Answer (score 0):

according to your description, you want to pass image path from one activity to another, you have to check the image path you get firstly, whether it is correct. then in another activity, check whether the path is transferred correctly.

Comment: not, I mean after load pictures from sd card, there popup "correct" and "load again" if I choose the "correct" then moved on to another activity .. and the load path of the image is sent to another activity and translated into imagview